# Emotion/React issue with third party package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, dependencies, vite

I will first copy and paste my vite.config.ts file and package.json file in my component being pushed to npm and installed along with the package.json of the project installing the package:

vite.config.ts:

````
```// vite.config.js

import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';


export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {'@emotion/react': '@emotion/react/jsx-runtime'},
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    })
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'lib/main.js'),
      name: 'KSDensityCalendar',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'ks-density-calendar',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['react', 'react-dom', "@mui/material", '@emotion/styled', '@emotion/react', '@mui/icons-material', '@date-fns', 'react/jsx-runtime'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          '@mui/material': '@mui/material',
          '@emotion/styled': '@emotion/styled',
          '@emotion/react': '@emotion/react',
          '@mui/icons-material': '@mui/icons-material',
          '@date-fns': '@date-fns',
          'react/jsx-runtime': 'react/jsx-runtime'
        },
      },
    },
  },
})```
````

component's package.json:

````
```{
  "name": "@lafarmer28/ks-density-calendar",
  "version": "0.1.19",
  "description": "A density calendar using MUI material, MUI icons-material, and date-fns with a month view, week view, and day view.",
  "type": "module",
  "types": "./src/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "chromatic": "",
    "storybook": "",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "author": "Lucas Asher Farmer",
  "license": "MIT",
  "registry": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.14",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/ks-density-calendar.js",
  "module": "./dist/ks-density-calendar.js",
  "exports": {
    "import": "./dist/ks-density-calendar.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.0.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.0.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.0.6",
    "@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm": "7.0.6",
    "@storybook/blocks": "7.0.6",
    "@storybook/react": "7.0.6",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "7.0.6",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "chromatic": "^6.17.3",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "storybook": "7.0.6",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.1",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "private": false
}```
````

project's package.json:

`````
````{
  "name": "client-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@lafarmer28/ks-density-calendar": "^0.1.15",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.17",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.16",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
}```
`````

I am getting error in the devTools when I render my custom component:

> You are loading @emotion/react when it is already loaded. Running
> multiple instances may cause problems. This can happen if multiple
> versions are used, or if multiple builds of the same version are used.

Is there something wrong with my configuration of my component that when I import and use it in my project I am loading it more than once? Or is this something with emotion/react at the versions I am using them in MUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining emotion in the dependencies of you package component. This means the package brings its own emotion while the app has already an instance of it loaded. This means conflict.

The solution is to move all the dependencies that are listed in extremal array of vite to peer dependencies. If you want to be able to locally work on the component package, you can  add them to dev dependencies as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I knew you had to move react and react-dom but I wasn't aware that those dependencies being used to render the component also had to be moved to peerDependencies. This was my first major complex component being pushed to npm and installed on another project.

Comment: Hi. I have a design system library which uses the same tech stack as the host. I use the dependencies to run the Storybook app and also demo React app within the same repo for testing. So is it possible to have them both in dependencies and peer dependencies? If not, shall I disable the lint error and move all libraries to the devDependencies + peerDependencies as I use the same tech stack in the host app? 

When I move some libraries to devDependencies:
`1:1  error  'dayjs' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies  import/no-extraneous-dependencies`